# Erro ao listar dados de SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Estou fazendo uma listagem das informações contidas no meu banco SQLite

No entanto, vezes ou outra, recebo o seguinte erro:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=13; index=1401

O intrigante que isso só ocorre de vez em quando, e se der erro e em seguida eu refazer a consulta o erro desaparece.

Alguém já passou por algo semelhante e/ou tem alguma ideia ?

```
    public class AgendaDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        // Database Info
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "agenda";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        // Table Name
        private static final String TABLE_NAME = "agenda";

        // Table Columns
        private static final String ID = "_id";
        private static final String DATA = "data";
        private static final String HORA = "hora";
        private static final String ID_USER = "iduser";
        private static final String NOME = "nome";
        private static final String DATA_AGENDAMENTO = "dataagendamento";
        private static final String OBSERVACOES = "observacoes";

        private static AgendaDatabaseHelper sInstance;

        Locale localeBR = new Locale("pt", "BR");
        SimpleDateFormat fmtDateBr = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",localeBR);
        SimpleDateFormat fmtDateSQL = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",localeBR);

        public AgendaDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }


        @Override
        public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onConfigure(db);
            db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String CREATE_AGENDA_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +"(" +
                ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                DATA + " DATE," +
                HORA + " TIME," +
                ID_USER + " INTEGER," +
                DATA_AGENDAMENTO + " DATE," +
                NOME + " TEXT," +
                OBSERVACOES + " TEXT" +
            ")";

            db.execSQL(CREATE_AGENDA_TABLE);
        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            if (oldVersion != newVersion) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + ";");
                onCreate(db);
            }
        }

        public static synchronized AgendaDatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
            if (sInstance == null) {
                sInstance = new AgendaDatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
            }else{
            }
            return sInstance;
        }


        public void insertAgenda(JSONObject item_Agenda) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            db.beginTransaction();

            try {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(ID, item_Agenda.getInt("ID"));
                values.put(ID_USER, item_Agenda.getInt("IDUSER"));

                if (item_Agenda.getString("DATA") != null && !item_Agenda.getString("DATA").isEmpty()) {
                    values.put(DATA, DateSQL(item_Agenda.getString("DATA")));
                }

                values.put(HORA, item_Agenda.getString("HORARIO"));
                values.put(NOME, item_Agenda.getString("NOME"));

                if (item_Agenda.getString("DATAAGENDAMENTO") != null && !item_Agenda.getString("DATAAGENDAMENTO").isEmpty()) {
                    values.put(DATA_AGENDAMENTO, DateSQL(item_Agenda.getString("DATAAGENDAMENTO")) );
                }
                values.put(OBSERVACOES, item_Agenda.getString("OBSERVACOES"));



                db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("TAG42", String.valueOf(e));
            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        }



        public List<Agenda> selectAgenda(String data, int idUser) {
            List<Agenda> agendaRegistros = new ArrayList<>();

            String POSTS_SELECT_QUERY = String.format(
                    "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = '%s' AND %s = %s ORDER BY %s ASC",
                    TABLE_NAME, DATA, DateSQL(data), ID_USER, idUser, HORA);
            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(POSTS_SELECT_QUERY, null);

            try {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        Agenda agendaRegistro = new Agenda();
                        agendaRegistro.setAgData(String.valueOf(fmtDateBr.format(fmtDateSQL.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DATA))))));
                        agendaRegistro.setAgHora(String.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HORA))).substring(0,5));

                        String datAgendamento = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DATA_AGENDAMENTO));

                        if ( datAgendamento != null && !datAgendamento.isEmpty()) {
                            agendaRegistro.setAgDataAgendamento(String.valueOf(fmtDateBr.format(fmtDateSQL.parse(datAgendamento))));
                        }else{
                        }

                        agendaRegistro.setAgNome(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOME)));
                        agendaRegistro.setAgObservacoes(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OBSERVACOES)));
                        agendaRegistros.add(agendaRegistro);

                    } while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("TAG42", String.valueOf(e));
                cursor.close();
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }

            return agendaRegistros;
        }


        public void deleteAgendaData(String data, int idUser) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                db.delete(TABLE_NAME, DATA + "=? AND " + ID_USER + "=?",
                        new String[] {
                                DateSQL(data),
                                String.valueOf(idUser)
                        });
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("TAG42", String.valueOf(e));
            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        }


        public void deleteAgendaUser(int idUser) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                db.delete(TABLE_NAME, ID_USER + "='" +idUser+"'", null);
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("TAG42", String.valueOf(e));
            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        }




        public static String DateBR(String DateSQL){
                String[] dataSplit = DateSQL.split("-");
                return dataSplit[2] + "/" + dataSplit[1] + "/" + dataSplit[0];
        }

        public static String DateSQL(String DateBR){
            String[] dataSplit = DateBR.split("/");
            return dataSplit[2] + "-" + dataSplit[1] + "-" + dataSplit[0];
        }


    }
```

Classe Agenda

```
    public class Agenda {
        private String _id;
        private String agData;
        private String agHora;
        private String agNome;
        private String agDataAgendamento;
        private String agObservacoes;

        public String get_id() {
            return _id;
        }

        public void set_id(String _id) {
            this._id = _id;
        }

        public String getAgData() {
            return agData;
        }

        public void setAgData(String agData) {
            this.agData = agData;
        }

        public String getAgHora() {
            return agHora;
        }

        public void setAgHora(String agHora) {
            this.agHora = agHora;
        }

        public String getAgNome() {
            return agNome;
        }

        public void setAgNome(String agNome) {
            this.agNome = agNome;
        }

        public String getAgDataAgendamento() {
            return agDataAgendamento;
        }

        public void setAgDataAgendamento(String agDataAgendamento) {
            this.agDataAgendamento = agDataAgendamento;
        }

        public String getAgObservacoes() {
            return agObservacoes;
        }

        public void setAgObservacoes(String agObservacoes) {
            this.agObservacoes = agObservacoes;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Agenda{" +
                    "_id='" + _id + '\'' +
                    ", agData='" + agData + '\'' +
                    ", agHora='" + agHora + '\'' +
                    ", agNome='" + agNome + '\'' +
                    ", agDataAgendamento='" + agDataAgendamento + '\'' +
                    ", agObservacoes='" + agObservacoes + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: pelo que pude perceber do código acima, esse erro deve estar na sua classe "Agenda", marca um brkpoint e debuga pra verificar e se ainda ficar sem saber o que fazer com o erro, posta aqui.

Comment: Coloca o código completo dessa classe e da classe Agenda.

Comment: Adicionei o códig da classe Agenda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema especificando o tamanho do ArrayList;

```
List<AgendaDia> agendaRegistros = new ArrayList<>(cursor.getCount());
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149372/java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-length-0-index-0-database-reading